# Changing the folder path in URL

Tags: php, url

Let's assume I have a website "`www.mywebsite.com`". I have a folder named "foo" and another folder named "bar" inside "foo". In "bar" folder, I have "aydin.php" file.

So, URL looks like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar/aydin.php
```

But, I want it to look like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/bar/aydin.php
```

or

```
www.mywebsite.com/abc/aydin.php
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL Rewriting with .htaccess file. You can find some information [here](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/)

Answer (score 1):

You must use [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

In your case I think .htaccess file should be like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^/abc/aydin.php$ /foo/bar/aydin.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- Change the webroot to /foo.
- Use URL rewriting. URL rewriting allows you to transform URLs in any way you want. It is usually a feature of your web server (e.g. [IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)).
- Make a file bar.php which handles all requests to /bar/blahblah.